# AngularJS directive doesn't render javascript on templateUrl page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I created an AngularJS directive that uses templateUrl to link to an html page which contains a graph. Basically I want to re-render a graph based on the users input. I thought the easiest way would be to make the graph a directive, and set the graphs input on a scope model.

**My directive:**

```
app.directive('ngGraph', function(){

return {templateUrl:'graph.html'}

});
```

**Graph.html**

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<h1>hello</h1>


<script>

// the values need to render graph;

</script>
```

Basically what is happening the `<h1>hello</h1>` renders in my index.html when I reference the directive but not the graph.

Comment: Try including your `<script>` tags in your main index.html, not in the directive template.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to initialise your graph element in your directive **link** function